# Laravel 5 Interface Binding in foreach

Tags: php, laravel, interface, bind

So I have the following set up, and it's working. Ofcourse I am using different class names, but the below is for better illustrating the code.

My question is within this:

```
foreach($groceries as $key => $value)
{
    App::bind('App\Interfaces\CalculateInterface', "App\Classes\\{$value}");

    echo App::make('App\Interfaces\CalculateInterface')->calculate();
}
```

For each value (the value is the class name as you can see below) I am binding and making a new interface, and within this example I am calling a particular method. I know there are better ways to use for what I am trying to achieve, but I was wondering if the way I am doing this in my foreach is a correct way to go about it, when using an interface? OR can this be done in a cleaner, "better" way perhaps?

PS. I am doing it this way, with an interface, because for each "Product" I require a different calculation. And later on I might add new classes or change existing ones. So personally I just wanted to do it like this.

Route:

```
Route::get('test', function () {

    $array = [
        'Test Product 1' => 'Class1',
        'Test Product 2' => 'Class2',
        'Test Product 3' => 'Class1',
    ];

    foreach($groceries as $key => $value)
    {
        App::bind('App\Interfaces\CalculateInterface', "App\Classes\\{$value}");

        echo App::make('App\Interfaces\CalculateInterface')->calculate();
    }

});
```

Interface:

```
interface CalculateInterface {
    public function calculate();
}
```

Class1:

```
class Class1 implements CalculateInterface {

    public function calculate() {
        echo 'This is the Class1 calculate method';
    }

}
```

Class2:

```
class Class2 implements CalculateInterface {

    public function calculate() {
        echo 'This is the Class2 calculate method';
    }

}
```

// etc...

Comment: In my opinion IoC binding in this example is not the correct way to do this. Actually Jeffrey has a great cast about such an example related to the [decorator design pattern](http://designpatternsphp.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Structural/Decorator/README.html) [here](https://laracasts.com/series/design-patterns-in-php/episodes/1).

Comment: Ah yes, thanks for pointing me to that video, those series were still on my watchlist :)